How can I target a particular twin in Autodesk Tandem to update its properties?
In Azure Digital Twins, I was able to use a twin's 'twin Id' to push values to it in real-time. I am currently testing Autodesk Tandem to evaluate which of the two services better fits my team's use case. However, I find Autodesk Tandem less intuitive, and the available documentation has not been particularly helpful. Specifically, I am unable to find an equivalent of twinId that would allow me to push values to a twin in real-time.
I tried creating 'Streams' for different twins and using their 'Stream URLs' to push real-time values. While this approach works, it requires me to keep track of all the 'Stream URLs' for each twin I want to update, which does not seem like a feasible solution for my team's use case.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

To push stream data you can use following steps:

Locate default model of your facility (twin). Then default model has same URL except of different prefix (urn:adsk.dtm instead of urn:adsk.dtt). Note than facility in Tandem can have multiple models (created by importing design files such as RVT or IFC). The default model is used to store Tandem specific elements.
Scan model for streams. Stream elements have flag set to 0x01000003.
Use POST timeseries/models/:modelID/webhooks/generic to send stream data. Note that payload can contain data for one or more streams (so it can be one object or array of objects). For example:

[
  'AQAAAH0dPikBrLw14ZY0Zci9DLhOZLnH': {
    temperature: 18.5
  },
  'AQAAAEpyWrYoHJ2ZccNedJ50peHzBT4y': {
    temperature: 16.3
  }
]

You can find more details here and here. There are code samples available on GitHub (JavaScript and Python.

Will this work if I have a free account? Does this require a paid account?

Yep, it works with free account as well. The limitation of free account is number of assets and stream history.

How to view dtm and dtt using the Tandem Web UI? I can look those details up using the Web UI and later use them wherever required in the APIs.

How will I know which Stream ID corresponds to which Asset in my Facility? I will have to handle so many Streams for each asset in my property that requires stream data.

The stream can be optionally linked to host element (i.e. asset). This information is stored using XParent (x:p) property. We have example how to locate host of the stream.

To your other question regarding accessing various URNs in Tandem web UI. You can find twin URN (= dtt) directly in the URL. You can also read stream key by using copy link button next to stream name. Other URNs (i.e. dtm) aren't directly accessing in the UI (except of using JavaScript in the console).

Thank you @Jan Liska, will go through and test it out
